# Why can't I download a pdf file since I upgraded to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, browser, pdf, foxit-reader, extension

---

I did a fresh installation of WIndows 10 pro x64 and I use several browsers, i.e.->

---

- *Firefox* portable ;
- Google *Chrome* portable ;
- *Internet* *explorer* (app and desktop) ;
- *Opera* portable.

---

I've always been using several extensions for my browsers so far, and I got them after the new installation of Windows; in particular, I installed the following add-ons and plug-ins->

---

- Adblock Plus        (on *Firefox* and *IE*)
- Adblock (on *Chrome* )
- DownThem all!       (on *Firefox* )
- Ghostery            (on *Firefox* and *IE*)
- NoScript            (on *Firefox* )
- Scriptsafe (on *Chrome*)
- pdfit               (on *Firefox* )
- SafePreview         (on *Firefox* )
- Unseen              (on *Firefox* )
- Wot                 (on *IE* )
- Avg Web Tune Up     (on *IE* )
- Webutation (on *Chrome*)
- Java Plug-in helper (in *IE*)
- OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems, Inc.    (on *Firefox* )
- Primetime Content Decryption Module provided by Adobe Systems, Incorporated    (on *Firefox* )
- Widevine Content Decryption Module provided by Google Inc.          (on *Firefox* )
- Java Deployment Toolkit 8.0.1110.14          (on *Firefox* )
- Java(TM) Platform SE 8 U111          (on *Firefox* )
- WacomTabletPlugin (on *Firefox* )

---

Now I'm trying to download a file (see [here](http://www.altroconsumo.it/Shared/ResourceDownload/?publicationUrlTitle=test-sulle-webcam-altroconsumo-221&ressourceUri=12790D652AEE0777315293142840AD5D2748FAEE) ; you may also try by clicking on the article *"Test sulle webcam (leggi l'articolo in pdf)"* [here](https://www.altroconsumo.it/cerca?keyword=test%20webcam&pageIndex=1&startFrom=0) ) , from a website from where I already downloaded such type of files in the past by using the same browsers on Windows 7 ultimate x64, and I never had any trouble before. I've been always using *Foxit reader* portable so far.
On the contrary, what I get now is the following error on *Firefox* and *Chrome* ->

---

> {"urlTitle":"test-sulle-webcam-altroconsumo-221","resultType":"stoppage"}

---

---

On *IE* I get a window asking me if I want to open or save a .json file (73 byte).

---

On *Opera* I get the following ->

[image]

but I cannot really choose the application I want to open the file with.

---

**Why can't I open or save a pdf file, whichever browser I use for this purpose?**
For I getting several troubles since I upgraded to Windows 10, I wonder if the issue described above may depend on the operative system...

Comment: Those aren't PDF files. Those are .json files. I realize the links on the website say they are PDFs, but they're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the exact same error within Firefox when I follow your hyperlink, and the only add-on I am using is Adblock Plus.  As a result, I am guessing that it is the source material rather than your web browsers.

Try downloading this one... it is a simple 4-page document comparing the features found in the various editions of Windows 10:

[Windows 10 Editions Comparison](http://wincom.blob.core.windows.net/documents/Win10EditionsCompareTable_FINAL.pdf)

If you can download that PDF file, your original problem is definitely related to the source material at the distant end.